# MySQL delete rows from other tables if deleted from main table

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have added a custom table in Wordpress DB called wp_likeandfollow, it contains these 4 columns

```
ID====following_id====follower_id====network_id
```

Here `follower_id` and `following_id` are the actual `ID` of users and there can be duplicate entries.
I want to have a check that if admin deletes a user from admin panel, then all entries of that user in `likeandfollow` table should also be deleted automatically and I want this to be done through MySQL automatically (not via PHP).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can set the following and follower ids as foreign keys to the users table and cascade on delete. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html for reference

Comment: show us the query you have made so far and schema!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger for this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_likes_and_follows AFTER DELETE on wp_users
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM wp_likeandfollow
        WHERE wp_likeandfollow.following_id = old.id;
END
```

where `old.id` will be `wp_users.id` in this case.

Comment: I am using this Query and after this, wordpress is not even deleting user from admin panel. When I remove the trigger, wordpress is able to delete then

CREATE TRIGGER `remove_likes_and_follows` BEFORE DELETE ON `rr_users`
 FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM rr_likeandfollow
 WHERE rr_likeandfollow.following_id=rr_users.ID